# unix script for simple text file modification

Tags: bash, unix

i have a file that look like this, the format should be filename followed by 4 entries beginning !.......

```
76669667-LD_TTFI9255.gz
!0c0901$
!02342e$
!0c0901$
!030c2a$
76669707-UN_TTFI5494.gz
!0c0901$
!030509$
76669731-IN_TTFI7570.gz
!0c0901$
!023633$
!0c0901$
!030e33$
```

I need a commmand that will find occasions where there are less than 4 entries after a file name and add in some blanks.

using example above the new output needs to become

```
76669667-LD_TTFI9255.gz
!0c0901$
!02342e$
!0c0901$
!030c2a$
76669707-UN_TTFI5494.gz
!0c0901$
!030509$
!?
!?
76669731-IN_TTFI7570.gz
!0c0901$
!023633$
!0c0901$
!030e33$
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be sed? Awk or perl would be much better suited for this. I don't think sed can easily do counting.

Comment: Even a simple bash `while read` loop would be easier than doing this in `sed`, I think.

Comment: happy to use awk or bash script ....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're happy to use more than just sed, awk or bash...

The following Perl script will do the trick:

```
cat input.txt | perl -pe '
    if (/^!/) {
        --$n
    } else {
        print "!?\n" x $n if $n > 0
        $n = 4
    }
    END {
        print "!?\n" x $n if $n > 0
    }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN {counter = 4}
     /^!/ {counter++; print}
     /^[^!]/ { for(i = counter; i<4; i++) print "!?"; print; counter=0; }
     END { for(i = counter; i<4; i++) print "!?"; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash solution. No code duplication as in the other answers :)

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while read line
do
  if [[ ! "$line" =~ ^! ]]
  then
      for((;count>0;count--))
      do
        echo "!?"
      done
      count=4
  else
      ((count--))
  fi
  echo "$line"
done < file
```